# Facilitate caching in MATLAB for big data analysis

Tags: matlab, caching

I am going to run twenty functions/procedures concurrently in MATLAB to analyse a big data set. Each function accesses to a part of this big data set. Caching is my main component which i need to show that MATLAB can use caching capacity. I want to:

1. each function reserve a cache space by default to save/modify/delete/look-up some content/data in its cache space
2. each function could request some desired content/data from other cache spaces which reserved by other functions

Could you please telling me how it is possible? I need some hints.

Comment: What "cache" are you talking about? All runtime variables in Matlab are stored in memory. The cache's in CPU are used in system level, not program. It's hard to imagine how to split one variable according to different functions.

Comment: About the caching by CPU, yes, you're right. But, I want to reserve a cache space by default for each function. I want to assign a private space to each function to just this function can access to corresponding caching space, and other functions just send a message to a desired caching space to request a content/data.

Comment: It's not always true the compiler that builds Matlab (and your operating system) is less clever than you about managing the cache. If so, you have to make sure sending messages between functions just for accessing "private cache" is more efficient than a regular, dynamically controlled way. --I really doubt why you surpass assembly, OS, and CPU, to control cache. Cache isn't a place you should consider to store data when writing Matlab code; they are designed to speed up the system in the lower level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check documentation on `persistent` variables in MatLab (and `mlock` function). It partially covers what you need. But then you'll face quite some problems with accessing the persistent variable and with the fact that persistent variables are cleared when the function source file is updated.

I would suggest to use files for your cache (of course, if I understand correctly what you mean).
For example, you may start with this approach (I assume that each function is in separate *.m file)

```
function CacheFileName = GenerateCacheFileName(Caller)
    CacheFileName = sprintf('%s.cache.mat',Caller);
    % you may use any alogrithm that makes sense for you
    % but keep the MAT extension for the simple syntax of LOAD function
end


function Data = LoadCachedData(Caller)
    % Generate cache file name for current function
    CacheFileName = GenerateCacheFileName(Caller);
    if exist(CacheFileName,'file')==2
        % load cache file if it exists
        RawData = load(CacheFileName);
        Data = RawData.CacheStructure;
    else
        % or initialize the cahce with empty structure
        Data = struct;
    end
end


function DoSomethingUsingCache(arguments)

    % Generate cache file name for current function
    CacheFileName = GenerateCacheFileName(mfilename);

    % Load cached data
    if exist(CacheFileName,'file'==2)
        % load cache file if it exists
        CacheStructure = load(CacheFileName);
    else
        % or initialize the cahce with current datestamp
        CacheStructure.Created = now;
    end

    % do what you need here

    % Save data to cache for later use
    save(CacheFileName,'CacheStructure');
end
```

If you need to load some data from other function, just do like this:

```
function DoSomethingUsingCacheOfOtherFunction(arguments)

    % Load chached data of other function
    CacheStructure2 = LoadCachedData('DoSomethingUsingCache');

    % do what you need here

    if isfield(CacheStructure,'Param4')
        CacheStructure.Param4 = CacheStructure.Param4 + 10;
    else
        CacheStructure.Param4 = 0;
    end

    % you may also update the cache for other function if you need
    save(CacheFileName2,'CacheStructure2');
end
```

Obviously, this approach should be designed properly otherwise MatLab will spend most of the time loading/saving your data.

In principle, this approach may be presented as MatLab class with set/get methods for easier code.
May be if you create an object in the root namespace you can use it as your "cached data manager".

Comment: This answer is a good one, if OP really means to store data in a "cache" file. Also, by using classes it's not hard to design a permission lock that separates a variable into several "private" spaces.

Comment: @anandr : in function 'DoSomethingUsingCache', the file cannot load, because MATLAB gives error as: `Unable to read file 'filename.cache.dat': no such file or directory.` I mean, i cannot load a file to write something on it.

Comment: @anandr : Why do you use CacheStructure in the single quotation in `save(CacheFileName,'CacheStructure');`, Because it is a variable. Am I right?

Comment: @BlueBit, have you put all functions in separate files? As for the `save` function see the documentation for it: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/save.html

Comment: @anandr , I put/save both functions `CacheFileName` and `DoSomethingUsingCache` in separate files. Next, I ran the function `DoSomethingUsingCache` by **F9**. Then, I faced with the error as: Error using load
Unable to read file 'DoSomethingUsingCache.cache.dat': 
_no such file or directory.

Error in DoSomethingUsingCache (line 7)
    CacheStructure = load(CacheFileName);_

Comment: @BlueBit, Ah, of course, because the file does not exist when you run the function first time. See correction for my code

Comment: @anandr, In the function `DoSomethingUsingCache` and in the `% do what you need here` section, I wrote **CacheStructure = 'aa'**. The problem is that, this string does not save in the file. Please check it. Thank you. and Why the saved `.dat` file has many parameter? How we can access to just **aa** value?

Comment: @BlueBit, I updated the code, it should work now. In any case this was just an example to demonstrate the concept. Now you should adapt it to your own task.